# Return selected values from one column matching a defined value in another column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, pivot-table, array-formulas

I would like to be able to input any `Dept#` in let's say cell D2 and have a formula already in cells A11, A12, A13, etc that will auto populate the `Subaccount` numbers based on the `Dept#` input.  One `Subaccount` per cell. Example:

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/5bhib.png]

Been looking at COUNTIF arrays still can't seem to figure it out or if it's even possible without using VBA.

Please note I do not use a Pivot Table nor a list with a drop down menu.  Also, cells F1 through H7 on the sample would be on another tab and the data table would be much larger with more columns.

Comment: This is an example BEGGING to use a pivot table.

Comment: Seriously use a pivot. You're wanting excel to behave like a custom built application, but you need to use it like it was designed.

Answer (score 2):

OP specifically states "i do not use a pivot table" but the general view seems to be that that is 'the way to go':

[image: SO15845224 example]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and I think your best off using `Index()`, `Match()`, `Small()` and `Row()`. As a mess, this is what you'll use in column `A` starting at `A11`:

```
{=INDEX($G$2:$G$9,MATCH(SMALL(IF($F$2:$F$9=$D$2,$F$2:$F$9,MAX($F$2:$F$9)+1)+
   ROW($F$2:$F$9)/100000,ROW()-10),$F$2:$F$9+ROW($F$2:$F$9)/100000,0))}
```

**Note:** I forgot to mention the above **NEEDS** to be entered as an array formula.

**Result:**
[image: Output]

**Explanation:** Keep in mind the steps explained below are done virtually.

1. The first step is to keep only the departments of interest and set the others to anything else larger than any other departments in the list. I've used the `Max() + 1`. Can't use the below in a cell.

   ```
   IF($F$2:$F$9 = $D$2, $F$2:$F$9, MAX($F$2:$F$9) + 1)
   ```
2. Alter the list of **Dep#** so none are the same using the `current_row_number / 100000`.

   ```
   ... + ROW($F$2:$F$9) / 100000
   ```
3. If your in row 11 this will be the first valid department number (`ROW()-10` will give you 1 if in `A11`) and now the list has the row number in it the first will be row 2. The `Small()` function will give you the smallest x:

   ```
   {=SMALL(IF($F$2:$F$9=$D$2,$F$2:$F$9,MAX($F$2:$F$9)+1)+
       ROW($F$2:$F$9)/100000,ROW()-10)}
   ```
4. Using `Match()` will now get you the row of the x value.

   ```
   {=MATCH(SMALL(IF($F$2:$F$9=$D$2,$F$2:$F$9,MAX($F$2:$F$9)+1)+
       ROW($F$2:$F$9)/100000,ROW()-10),$F$2:$F$9+ROW($F$2:$F$9)/100000,0)}
   ```
5. Now you have the row of all the relevant departments use the `Index` function the retrieve the appropriate subaccount.

   ```
   {=INDEX($G$2:$G$9,MATCH(SMALL(IF($F$2:$F$9=$D$2,$F$2:$F$9,MAX($F$2:$F$9)+1)+
       ROW($F$2:$F$9)/100000,ROW()-10),$F$2:$F$9+ROW($F$2:$F$9)/100000,0))}
   ```

Comment: I'm adding an explanation to explain but this will get you their.

Comment: @pnuts, Good point to capture the remaining rows, `Iferror(..., "")`. Lets make this formula **MORE** complex ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is versatile enough but seems OK for the sample provided, so may at least be the pointer you would settle for:

In `A11` enter `=VLOOKUP($D$2,F1:$G$8,2,FALSE)` (as adjusted for the fact that your table is on a different tab). This assumes there will always be at least one Subaccount per Dept#, so is a little simpler than the formula for `A12` (to be copied down to `A19`):

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D$2,INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(A11,G:G,0)+1&":$G$8"),2,FALSE),"")

I think this proves your requirements can be be met but I acknowledge some tweaking may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer seems to work for the sample data used by @glh so hopefully both are viable! But you are (in my view sensibly) open to suggestions and I would say better than the convoluted formulae in both those answers is to establish a separate table, say Row1 each Dept# in a separate column and below each Dept# enter (mainly as a 'once off') every possible Subaccount for that department. Then populating `A11:A19` would be *very* much easier and I think you would have better control because this would be based on expected combinations rather than actual ones.

But my preference would still probably be for a PivotTable.

Comment: +1, pivot table is defiantly what this needs and it will provide a dropdown for the users to select a value